# Calling function from different project in codeblocks

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, codeblocks

I have implemented a BST in one project name BST in codeblocks and now currently I'm implementing AVL Tree in different project and since some function are common like inorder traversal and insertion in BST, so instead of writing the codes again I want to import them from BST to AVL. Is there any way to do so in Codeblocks ? If yes then how ?

Comment: I think no, only inside the same project can be read each others

Comment: You need to build either a static or dynamic library out of BST. In your AVL project you then need the header, which defines the accessible definitions in your BST library. You can configure your AVL project to link the BST library statically in your AVL build. All Integrated Development Environments like CodeBlocks provide the possibility to customize your compiler and linker calls. However, if you need more information, you need to give also more information about your build environment (operating system, compiler, etc.).

Comment: I agree with @tangoal, using library is the standard method.